# Updating mobileNumber using graph giving { }

Tags: graph, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication, azure-ad-b2b

I would like to add phone number to existing Azure AD users. I don't want them to manually enter their phone numbers to get code for MFA.

I am trying to do this from graph like this:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/id

{
  "mobileNumber" : "############"
}
```

This gave me `No content - 204` status with empty brackets { }

Now I can see phone number added on user profile but it is still asking users to enter phone number to get code.

How can  automate this process? Any ideas

PS: I have administrator role on my tenant so I hope I'm not missing any permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please **note** that, you need to create **phone authentication method** instead of updating **`mobileNumber`** property in user's profile.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

To create phone authentication method, I used below graph query:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>/authentication/phoneMethods

{
"phoneNumber": "+91 9xxxxx4004",
"phoneType": "mobile"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked in Azure Portal, phone number added successfully in user's **Authentication methods** like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Users -> Your user -> Authentication methods***

[image]

When user tried to sign in, it automatically displayed **added phone number** like below:

[image]

When user selected that option, they will **receive code** to their phone number which they need to enter here:

[image]